# Passing table name as a parameter in psycopg2, relation does not exist for a public table

Tags: python, postgresql, parameter-passing, psycopg2

It seems like passing table name as a parameter in psycopg2 doesn't work for an outside public table. The code and result as below.Appreciate any helps.

This code works well.
`cursor.execute('select * from public.wc_test limit 1')`

However, this code returns an error
`cursor.execute(sql.SQL('select * from {} limit 1').format(sql.Identifier('public.wc_test')))`

> ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 cursor.execute(sql.SQL('select * from {} limit 1').format(sql.Identifier('public.wc_test')))
>   ProgrammingError: relation "public.wc_test" does not exist
>   LINE 1: select * from "public.wc_test" limit 1

[Here is the screenshot of the code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceppf.png)

**New Issue:**

It seems I got the same issue again with another table, even I separated the schema and the table name. Do you have any ideas what results in this error? Thanks!

[Here is the screenshot of the code and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTHOS.png)

Comment: You need to do the `.format` on the `str` instead of `SQL` object: cursor.execute(sql.SQL('select * from {} limit 1'.format(sql.Identifier('public.wc_test'))))

Comment: @bow Should be an answer

Answer (score 2):

The schema and table name must be passed separately otherwise they will finish being quoted together like in `"public.wc_text"` where it should be `"public"."wc_test"`. So either

```
cursor.execute(
    sql.SQL('select * from public.{} limit 1').format(
        sql.Identifier('wc_test')
    )
)
```

or

```
cursor.execute(
    sql.SQL('select * from {}.{} limit 1').format(
        sql.Identifier('public'),
        sql.Identifier('wc_test')
    )
)
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi there, your solution has worked well, but I got the same issue again when I worked with a table. Could you help me check it again, I have added more details above under "New Issue"? Do you have any ideas why I got this issue this time? Please  Let me know if you need more info about it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you check the comment above? Thank you! @Clodoaldo

Comment: @WenqiCheng Post another question with the exact code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AsIs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs) postrgresql extension method for this:

> Adapter conform to the ISQLQuote protocol useful for objects whose string representation is already valid as SQL representation.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

QUERY = 'SELECT * from %(table)s limit 1'

data = {'table': AsIs('public.wc_test')}

with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(QUERY, data)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()        
return rows
```